# Using quick draw with a grappling hook?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, equipment

I was running a game and one of my players (a brawler) was going to have troubles getting over a wall so they wanted to get their [grappling hook](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/tools-kits#TOC-Hook-Grappling) out. They wanted to use quick draw to get it out, but as it wasn't a weapon I treated it like a wand so that it wasn't usable with quick draw. It will also matter **where** he will be keeping it from now on.

Now the grappling hook is actually listed under the [exotic ranged weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#exotic-ranged) list and then redirects you into the equipment. At the time I didn't know it was actually listed as a weapon.

Since it is listed as a weapon, does that mean that it can actually be used with quick draw? This also implies that they should take negatives by not being proficient, or would the [throw anything](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/throw-anything-combat---final) feat cover this?

Comment: Related: [Why does Quick Draw not apply to alchemical items?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/27800/9625)

Comment: If you want to ask about the ranged attack roll required for grappling hooks, you should do so in a separate question and not edit an old question into an entirely new one. :)

Comment: The answers here are *slightly* invalidated now, and I can't seem to roll the question back to it's original version. (The version "Can quick draw be used with grappling hooks?")

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah, sorry about your nice answer down there. Was just about to break it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page [Locks, Keys, Tools, and Kits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/tools-kits), we see that:

> Throwing a grappling hook requires a ranged attack roll, treating the hook **as a thrown weapon** with a range increment of 10 feet. Objects with ample places to catch the hook have an AC of 5. [Source (PFSRD)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/tools-kits#TOC-Hook-Grappling), *emphasis mine*)

So, therefore, Grappling hooks may be *Quick Drawn.*

(*But is the rope already tied to the hook?*)

Without house-ruling, your player would have to be [Mythic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic) in order to draw *any* item:

> **Quick Draw (Mythic)** 
>   You can use Quick Draw to draw items of any kind, not just weapons, provided they are stored or concealed on your person. As a move action, you can expend one use of mythic power to retrieve up to two hidden items. You must have two hands free to do so. [Source (PFSRD)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-feats/quick-draw-mythic)

Answer (score 3):

A grappling hook is treated as a thrown weapon. So it can be Quick Drawn, but the Throw Anything feat doesn't cover this since it isn't an improvised throwing weapon.

The grappling hook *exotic weapon* is a different kind of weapon, since this has a different price than the normal adventuring hook. The Throw Anything feat still doesn't apply.

To see for yourself:
[The grappling hook weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons)
[The grappling hook tool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/tools-kits#TOC-Hook-Grappling)
(For easier searching: ctrl+f and type in "grappling hook".)

EDIT: Posted before the question got edited.

Comment: I didnt realize there were two different ones, but both the weight and cost are different.

Comment: It seems that they are two different items, but got the same name.

Comment: Here is the full description found on Pirates of the Inner Sea: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qh4m?Grappling-with-a-grappling-hook#2

Answer (score 0):

All physical items can be used as improvised weapons, and thus can be quickdrawn.  There is a mythic upgrade that lets you do this without treating them as an improvised weapon, but this 'upgrade' is redundant and doesn't actually do anything.  You can quick draw a grapple hook, as well as a rope, wand, boot, potion bottle, arrow, or really anything else.