# Can you draw a wand while walking?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, action-economy

Under the "Draw a weapon" heading, [the PRD states that](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Draw-or-Sheathe-a-Weapon):

1. You can draw a weapon with a move action. This also applies to wands.
2. You can draw a weapon on the move, if you have at least +1 BAB.

This last paragraph can be parsed in two different ways:

- You can **draw a weapon** (the whole action that also applies to wands)
- You can **draw** *a weapon* (and not a wand)

Which is the correct one?

Comment: Are you asking about using the move action to actually move and draw an easily accessible weapon type action?

Comment: @Fering that one

Answer (score 9):

No.

> If you have a base attack bonus of +1 or higher, you may **draw a weapon** as a free action combined with a regular move. If you have the Two-Weapon Fighting feat, you can draw two light or one-handed weapons in the time it would normally take you to draw one.

As we can see from the description, it specifies a weapon for the action you want.

If we examine [wands](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wands) themselves we see that all the descriptive elements fail to call it a weapon. This is further enforced by wands failing to appear on the [weapon list](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons) under equipment.

[Quick draw](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/quick-draw-combat-final/) which is a continuation

> Alchemical items, potions, scrolls, and wands cannot be drawn quickly using this feat.

Now, you might be able to convince your GM to treat a wand as an improvised weapon and thus can be drawn that way, but its weak reasoning because its basically a fake weapon.

[Improvised Weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/)

> Sometimes objects not crafted to be weapons nonetheless see use in combat. Because such objects are not designed for this use, any creature that uses an improvised weapon in combat is considered to be nonproficient with it and takes a –4 penalty on attack rolls made with that object. To determine the size category and appropriate damage for an improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential to the weapon list to find a reasonable match. An improvised weapon scores a threat on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a critical hit. An improvised thrown weapon has a range increment of 10 feet.

I have struggled with the same issue of quickly drawing a wand and not wasting so many actions, or worse switching wands and not dropping. There are no real good rules for you. [Gloves of Storing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/glove-of-storing/) would work, but its expensive for a single item.

Comment: It's like *Pathfinder* thought that by making wands slower to draw, the game believed it was nerfing casters, the game not realizing it's folks who *aren't* serious casters that are the most frequent users of wands! By the way, +1ed. This was my conclusion, too, even down to the examination of the feat Quick Draw.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Thank you for the praise, since I see the quality of your answers and look up to them, it means a lot. Whats the +1ed mean however?

Comment: You're welcome. *+1ed* means I upvoted it.

Comment: Ah, I understand now

Comment: How unfortunate that there's a lot of NPCs using wands in these Adventure Paths.

Comment: @Zachiel Well, as stupid as it sounds, some of the rods are weapons in their own right, but Ive honestly never heard of anyone using them for attacks. The rods descriptions mentions this.

Comment: The rationale I've seen used against this answer is that "draw a weapon" is actually described in the paragraph above as the act of drawing a weapon or a wand". Isn't there any official clarification on the intent?

Comment: @Zachiel There was in *3.5e* where—officially—almost anything that could vaguely be construed as a weapon could be drawn in such a way, but *Pathfinder* has made no attempts (so far as I'm aware) to follow it's forebear's lead and, in fact, with *Pathfinder*'s changes to the feat Quick Draw, has taken a conscious step backward. (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/27800/8610).)

Comment: Well said. You may want to add [Efficient Quiver](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/efficient-quiver) as a method of drawing wands quickly. It doesn't specifically allow drawing on the movement, but a nice GM may allow it.

Comment: @Ifusaso You make a valid point, the quiver does allow anything in it other than just arrows. The issue still remains that once you draw one or two wands, thats it unless you start dropping them

Comment: @Ifusaso as a DM, adding extra magic items to my NPCs means injecting too much gold into the Adventure Path

Comment: I understand. I'd already upvoted, I just recalled one of my fellow players using a prehensile tail and Efficient Quiver to great effect

Comment: @Ifusaso How did they use the tail to great effect? The extra appendage is weak and can only carry light stuff, which a wand would be, but drawing and putting away should still be the same as if you had the two normal arms.

Comment: Turns it into a Swift action, and gives them a third 'slot' for objects